# How can I fix this error with tensorflow warning?

Tags: tensorflow

When the programme has been started in the console outputting:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.base. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.checkpoint_management has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.checkpoint_management. The old module will be deleted in version 2.9.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.resource has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.resource. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.util has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.checkpoint. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.base_delegate has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.base_delegate. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.graph_view has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.graph_view. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.tracking.python_state has been moved to tensorflow.python.trackable.python_state. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.saving.functional_saver has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.functional_saver. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
WARNING:tensorflow:Please fix your imports. Module tensorflow.python.training.saving.checkpoint_options has been moved to tensorflow.python.checkpoint.checkpoint_options. The old module will be deleted in version 2.11.
```

How to fix this?

update
[there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIawt.png)

Comment: do you get these warnings also when importing tensorflow and not any other libraries?

Comment: only tensorflow

Comment: These are not errors, just warnings. Is this causing your code to stop? If not, you can ignore them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reduce the amount of warnings given by tensorflow all you need to do is define how much you want to avoid changing your os.environ variable here is a sample. 1 will make sure nothing is printed

```
import os.
import tensorflow as tf.
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '1'
```

Comment: i does it, but message also are imported (look update)

Comment: This is correct for general warnings and errors i.e; excessive tracing in a `tf.function` graph, binaries not compiled for the architecture, etc. but this does not work for deprecation warnings, by design. See [this thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27023) for more details. To suppress deprecation warnings, the `deprecations. _PRINT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS` flag has to be set (detailed in my response).

Answer (score 2):

Can you try setting the log level before you import tensorflow?

```
import os
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = "2"
import tensorflow as tf
```

Answer (score 1):

The logging occurs in [this function](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.11.0-rc1/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py#L673):

```py
  def getter(name):
    if getter not in _PRINTED_WARNING and _PRINT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS:
      _PRINTED_WARNING[getter] = True
      logging.warning(
          'Please fix your imports. Module %s has been moved to %s. The old '
          'module will be deleted in version %s.', deprecated_name,
          new_module.__name__, deletion_version)
    return getattr(new_module, name)

  return getter
```

In various modules, you'll find:

```py
deprecation.deprecate_moved_module(
    __name__, <MODULE_NAME>, "<VERSION_NUMBER>")
```

One example from the snippet provided is [tensorflow.python.training.saving.checkpoint_options](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.11.0-rc1/tensorflow/python/training/saving/checkpoint_options.py#L22):

```py
from tensorflow.python.checkpoint import checkpoint_options
from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation

__getattr__ = deprecation.deprecate_moved_module(
    __name__, checkpoint_options, "2.11")
```

which indicates importing from that module is being deprecated in 2.11 (although it will still technically work until then).

Based on the snippet provided, it does not appear you're directly importing these modules, but an external dependency or a different module may be. If fixing the imports is not possible, in the same `deprecations` module, there is a [context manager](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.11.0-rc1/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py#L664) called `silence`, which changes the global variable `_PRINT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS` to False within the context block and will therefore prevent the warning logs from surfacing. The use would be something like:

```py
from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation

with deprecation.silence():
    <INSERT_CODE_HERE>
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to put a large code block within a context manager, you could just set the variable `_PRINT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS` directly at the top of your module:

```py
from tensorflow.python.util import deprecation
deprecation._PRINT_DEPRECATION_WARNINGS = False
<INSERT_CODE_HERE>
```

Note that setting the environment variable `TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL` to 1-3 for reduced logging does **not apply for deprecation warnings**, as discussed in [this thread](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27023).